# Custom video thumbnails via Twitter API?

Tags: video, twitter, upload, tweets

Is there a way to set a custom thumbnail for a video via Twitter API? I can't seem to find any reference to this?

Comment: I'm trying to figure this out as well - the only references I can find to it are via the Ads API as custom poster frames.

Comment: I think you might need to use this: https://media.twitter.com/content/media-twitter/en_us/articles/products/2018/pro-media-api.html

Comment: UPDATE:  You need to use the Pro media api